# ConfigParser cannot pop section that exists with a no section error

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser

I'm trying to make a settings manager for my UI app and I keep getting this error in the below code:

```py
class SettingsManager:
    def __init__(self, settings_file: str):
        if not os.path.isfile(settings_file):
            open(settings_file, "w").close()

        self._settings_file = settings_file
        self._config = ConfigParser()
        self._config.read(settings_file)

        # Backwards compatibility
        if self._config.has_section("user_settings"):
            # Rename "user_settings" section to "main" section.
            self._config["main"] = self._config.pop("user_settings")
```

```bash
  File "/Users/test/programming/onGAU/onGAU/settings_manager.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._config["main"] = self._config.pop("user_settings")
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/configparser.py", line 993, in __setitem__
    self.read_dict({key: value})
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/configparser.py", line 763, in read_dict
    for key, value in keys.items():
  File "<frozen _collections_abc>", line 860, in __iter__
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/configparser.py", line 1292, in __iter__
    return self._options().__iter__()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/configparser.py", line 1296, in _options
    return self._parser.options(self._name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/configparser.py", line 690, in options
    raise NoSectionError(section) from None
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'user_settings'
```

And here's my .ini file:

```ini
[user_settings]
model = a
prompt = a
negative_prompt = a
seed = 123
pipeline = Text2Img
scheduler = DPMSolverMultistepScheduler Karras
base_image_path =
guidance_scale = 9.0
step_count = 2
image_amount = 2
width = 720
height = 480
safety_checker = True
attention_slicing = True
vae_slicing = False
xformers_memory_attention = False
compel_weighting = False
clip_skip = 2
lpwsd_pipeline = True
upscale_amount = 2
```

I've also tried:

```py
self._config.add_section("main")
self._config["main"] = self._config.pop("user_settings")
```

and

```py
section = self._config.pop("user_settings")
self._config["main"] = section
```

but both also don't work.

I can print the section's values before and I even check if the section exists first before popping it. Why does this still happen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `settings_file` must refer to some other filepath, which is not the file you thought it was.  When you call `SettingsManager()`, are you passing a plain filename, or a full path?  Can you show us the call to `SettingsManager()`?

Comment: I've tested with both a fullpath and a relative path. `SettingsMananger("/Users/test/programming/onGAU/onGAU/user_settings.ini")`

Comment: `/Users/test/programming/onGAU/onGAU/user_settings.ini` And is that actually the correct path to the file?  (Is `/onGAU` supposed to be in there twice?)

Comment: Yes, I copied the full absolute path using the file explorer. Also wouldn't I not be able to check if the .ini file has that section if the path is wrong?

Comment: Confusingly, `config.read("somefile.ini")` does NOT throw an exception if the named file does not exist.  It just does nothing.

Comment: You said you copied the path from file explorer, which could be the issue.  By default, File Explorer does not show file extensions, so the real filename might be something like `user_settings.ini.ini`.  Try this small test: `import os; print(os.listdir("/Users/test/programming/onGAU/onGAU"))`

Comment: Tried it and the path is still the same.

Comment: What was the output of that print statement?

Comment: Also, show us the output of this code `print(open("/Users/test/programming/onGAU/onGAU/user_settings.ini").read())`

Comment: Here's the output copied:
```
[user_settings]
(too long to be put in a comment but all the settings are the same as in the user_settings.ini file if I open it in a text editor)
```